# How to set span's text from text area on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the text in a span from a text area's value when the page has loaded.

I have a span:

```
<span id='message'></span>
```

I have a text area which I set the value for with a rails variable:

```
<%= f.text_area :text_message, value: @user.text_message, id: 'text_message' %>
```

When the page has loaded I want the span's text to be the same as the text areas text. Something like (which doesn't work):

```
(document).ready(function() {     
  var message_text = $("#text_message").value;
    $("#message").html(message_text);
});
```

Comment: I think you missed a `$` when copying your code.

Comment: WHY THE DOWN VOTE? IT WAS A WELL STRUCTURED QUESTION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery object doesn't have the definition of `value` it is in javascript.

Use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function for it.

```
var message_text = $("#text_message").val();
```

and you also forgot to use `$`with document object

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
  var message_text = $("#text_message").val()
    $("#message").html(message_text);
});
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W8AWF/)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `DOM` object property value with `jQuery` object. You need to use `val()` instead of `value`. The `value` attribute could only be assessed with javascript DOM object but not with jQuery object.

*Change*

```
var message_text = $("#text_message").value
```

*To*

```
var message_text =  $("#text_message").val();
```

OR, use `indexer` to convert the `jQuery` object to `DOM` object.

```
var message_text = $("#text_message")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

on dom ready use

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
  var message_text = $("#text_message").val();
    $("#message").text(message_text);
});

$(document).ready(function() {     
  var message_text = $("#text_message").val();
    $("#message").html(message_text);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `.value` to grab the content.

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    var message_text = $("#text_message").text();
    $("#message").html(message_text);
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zpYLF/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `text()` to set the text insted of `html()`  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/TtDyn/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {//$ is missing here     
    var message_text = $("#text_message").value
    $("#message").text(message_text);
});
```

When ypu set the text the span wiil be for example0:

```
<span id="message">hi</span> //here hi is set as text
```